# Does H.265/HEVC macroblock/CTU algorithm compensate for 4:3 letterbox in 1920x1080

Tags: ffmpeg, video-encoding, h.265, aspect-ratio, x265

Have some source in 1920x1080 but it's actually 4:3 with letterbox. One path is to crop the video to remove the black letterbox and bring it down to 1440x1080 but is that really necessary when encoded in H.265?

Would appropriately sized CTUs be created to cover the black sections (no motion)?

Will there be a difference in file size as a result cropping vs non cropping in this situation?

Comment: As far as I know the algorithm doesn't have special treatment for black margins. In theory there is a way to select different quality for different regions (I never saw it in practice). Encode your video file with and without cropping, and give us your insights.

Comment: @Rotem Not for black margins per se. But in generally any large single color areas can be compressed really really well! "Solid color areas" in both the space domain (large continuous area, good for maximum intra frame compression) and the time domain (no visual noise, good for maximum inter frame compression).

Comment: Simple experiment with a PNG: 1) Make a quite dynamic/vivid 100x100px image. Save. take note of file size. 2) Increase canvas to 1000x1000px, original remains top-left, rest filled with single color. Save. Filesize not linearly larger at all. Only little larger. 3) Increase canvas again to 2000x2000px, original still remains top left. Save. Filesize again grew only very little. Why? Because continuous monotone color areas compress really really well!

Comment: So videos coming from a clean digital source (no visual noise as on analog film) with a real solid letterbox/pillarbox which takes up e.g. 20% of the image dimensions, maybe only causes a file size increase of maybe 1-3% in comparison to a cleanly cropped one. These are assessed not measured numbers, but somehow in that dimension it will be.

Answer (score 1):

In short, it looks like it works out well enough anyway.

I did one encode pass with cropping vs one without and there was only a 7MB difference between the output files.

I have used appropriate mostly default Handbrake profile.

Comment: Related: Recently too thought to **ideally crop along macroblock lines when re-encoding**. But slightly different. Far worse source material than you: DVD video, PAL, MPEG-2, 720x576. With both a letterbox and a pillarbox. The pillarbox on the left being 8-10px (unstable, jitters a bit over time), right 14-16px. The source material has noticible blocking (visible macroblocks). So I thought if I crop and re-encode, then at least crop along the macroblocks, for best possible re-encoding. Else the intra-frame encoding needs to average out pixels from neighboring macroblocks. Efficiency horror!

Comment: **Ideally crop in full macroblock multiples on the left and right. Or at least on the left!** B/c I assume the blocks are ordered L→R. Because if the left cropping is not exactly a macroblock, **all following** macroblocks to the right are a "remix" of previously neighboring macroblocks. Information efficiency nightmare! Whereas cropping a full multiples, leaves all further macroblocks metrics intact. And the righthand crop only affects the last (few) macroblock(s).

Comment: **The same for top to bottom. Crucial to crop the top one exactly along a macroblock** (and sacrifice a few pixels if needed) so that all further macroblocks below remain aligned, except the bottom macroblock(s) which may get cropped unevenly.